# Powershell cmdlet that returns an object containing default gateway for interface

Tags: powershell

I have searched up and down Microsoft's documentation for a cmdlet that returns an object containing the default gateway for an interface. I know Get-NetIPConfiguration returns the default gateway however, it does not return an object for me to use. Any ideas?

Edit here is what i am running. I am trying to automatically change a nic's ip address and for that i need the default gateway of the nic.

```
$ip =  Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceIndex 17
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress (New Ip address) -PrefixLength (Current Prefix length) -DefaultGateway $ip.IPv4DefaultGateway
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are expecting, for me this returns an object: `Get-NetIPConfiguration|Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -or $_.IPv6DefaultGateway}|Format-List *`

Comment: [edit] your question to contain additional/updated information, don't put that into comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell things are not always what they seem. Presentation of objects on screen can be filtered for the sake of readability. Like here:

```
PS> Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceIndex 8
InterfaceAlias       : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex       : 8
InterfaceDescription : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
NetProfile.Name      : xxxxxx
IPv4Address          : 10.0.0.26
IPv6DefaultGateway   :
IPv4DefaultGateway   : 10.0.0.251
DNSServer            : 10.0.0.251
                       212.54.35.25
                       212.54.40.25
```

It seems like IPv4DefaultGateway is just a string containing an ip address. But it isn't:

```
PS> (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceIndex 8).ipv4defaultgateway

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore PSComputerName
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -------- ----------- --------------
8       0.0.0.0/0                                      10.0.0.251                                         0 45       ActiveStore
```

Now you can see that IPv4DefaultGateway has members and NextHop is the member that contains the actual ip address of the gateway. Sometimes you need to peel off objects to find out what's in it. Not used here, but `Get-Member` can be very helpful in these matters

So the code you need is this:

```
$ip =  Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceIndex 17
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress (New Ip address) -PrefixLength (Current Prefix length) -DefaultGateway $ip.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there documentation i can read or a rule of thumb you used to figure it out?

Comment: I will edit my answer to explain how to find out things like this